# Redshift - Passing output from SQL to different variables

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-redshift

I have a SQL script that extracts sale data by agent.

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""select sales_rep,to_char(sales_date,'yyyy-mm')as month,count(*) from sale""")
report = cur.fetchall()
```

I am trying to see if I can pass count obtained from the output to a variable (count) and month value to another variable (month_count).

Could anyone advice on this. Thanks.

**Update :**

Sample Output:

```
Sales_Rep,Month,Count
Person1,Jan,20
Person1,Feb,15
Person1,Mar,10
Person2,Jan,8
Person2,Feb,13
Person2,Mar,15
```

Expected Output:

```
count = 20,15,108,13,15
month = jan,feb,mar,jan,feb,mar
```

Comment: Please show sample input and output data.  Your current query should not even run, I think.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I have updated my initial post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a basic group by query here:

```
SELECT
    sales_rep,
    TO_CHAR(sales_date, 'yyyy-mm') AS month,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM sale
GROUP BY
    sales_rep,
    TO_CHAR(sales_date, 'yyyy-mm');
```

Python code:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""SELECT sales_rep, TO_CHAR(sales_date, 'yyyy-mm') AS month, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM sale GROUP BY sales_rep, TO_CHAR(sales_date, 'yyyy-mm')""")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print("{} " + row["month"]).format(row["cnt"])
```

Comment: how could I call these column separately output of this sql script. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: @scottmartin Check my updated answer.  I added some Python code.